# How can I change the parameter font style italic?

Tags: javascript, arrays, visual-studio-code

I want to change the parameter font style like this image. How can I do this? [my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCexj.png) [another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjuVq.png)

Comment: this isn't a question about code or a problem with code, look at vsc [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) or changing cursive font [blog](https://www.ankursheel.com/blog/add-cursive-fonts-to-vs-code)

Comment: This is likely due to the font/theme/syntax highlighting being used in, what looks like, VS Code. This isn't really a programming question, but instead is more of a software configuration question.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [Working with themes in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) & [Working with javascript in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript)

File should be jsconfig.json
Change font like following in json

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

    "textMateRules": [
        {
        "scope": "variable.parameter.function",
        "settings": {
                     "fontStyle": "",
                     "foreground":"#d15a32"
                    }
         }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply your own customization, just enter your `settings.json`

```json
"editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace"
```

There is also this possibility that you can change some rules in your editor:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "variable.parameter"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

In the example I did above, it will underline all parameters.
However, changing the font does not work.

Is there a way to do this? Sure, but I don't know.
I know that some vscode themes change, one that I can quote is DarkMono.